# Alfresco CIFS Server ERROR

Tags: tcp, imap, alfresco, smb, cifs

When I restart Alfresco, it starts... I got the page... But on the logs I got the error:

```
 2015-11-10 09:58:55,282  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default]
 2015-11-10 09:58:55,291  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [CIFS Server] [SMB] Server error : org.alfresco.jlan.server.config.InvalidConfigurationException: Error initializing TCP-IP SMB session handler, Permissão negada
 2015-11-10 09:58:55,301  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [CIFS Server] Error from JLAN
 org.alfresco.jlan.server.config.InvalidConfigurationException: Error initializing TCP-IP SMB session handler, Permissão negada
    at org.alfresco.jlan.smb.server.nio.NIOCifsConnectionsHandler.initializeHandler(NIOCifsConnectionsHandler.java:259)
    at org.alfresco.jlan.smb.server.SMBServer.run(SMBServer.java:479)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-11-10 09:58:55,360  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default] complete
```

What is the error? How can I solve that?

Comment: Does the user running Alfresco have permissions to those ports?

Comment: Depends on what operating system you're running. If you don't know how to check, [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) might be a better place for the question of how to do the check

Comment: Thanks. I posted there ;)

Comment: I already got the solution on the post of the ServerFault, but your answer was correct. So if you want to write in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key part of that error message is:

```
Error initializing TCP-IP SMB session handler, Permissão negada
```

That is telling you that when Alfresco tries to bind (via JLAN) to the port(s) needed to offer CIFS/SMB, it is getting permission denied

As you've [found out over on your related question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/735291/76753), on Linux by default a normal user can't bind to ports below 1024. CIFS/SMB make heavy use of ports down in the one hundred range, which regular users aren't allowed to listen on. Details of how to check that and how to fix it are a bit out of scope for StackOverflow, luckily they're [covered in the answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/735291/76753) :)

The other common error from that bit of code is "Address already in use", which you'll see if something else is already listening on the port(s) needed, eg another Alfresco server, or the machine's own CIFS/SMB stack.